# XMP data encrypted on Canon EOD D1000

Tags: actionscript-3, encryption, air, xmp

I have a question regarding encryption, once again this relates to reading serial numbers from the `aux:SerialNumber` namespace.

When I open my file in AS3 from photos of the Canon EOS D1000, it can't read this bit in the `ByteArray` `var i:int = p.search('<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="\'dobe:ns:meta/\'');` because well its encrypted.

What makes this interesting is, if I open the file in Photoshop then save it and close it the XMP data is correct and my app can read it.

My question would be how would I decrypt the XMP data from within AS3? Is there a way to do it. Or  another way to read it?

This is the method I use:

```
private function getXMP(ba:ByteArray):XML
{   
    var LP:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    var PACKET:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    var l:int;

    ba.readBytes(LP, 2, 2);

    //http://www.adobe.com/devnet/xmp.html read part 3: Storage in Files.           
    //that will explain the -2 -29 and other things you see here.

    l = LP.readInt() - 2 -29;
    ba.readBytes(PACKET, 33, l);

    var p:String = trim(""+PACKET);
    var i:int = p.search('<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/"');
    //Delete all in front of the XMP XML
    p = p.substr(i);

    //For some reason this left some rubbish in front, so I'll hardcode it out for now 

    var ar:Array = p.split('<');
    var s:String = "";
    var q:int;
    var j:int = ar.length;

    for(q=1;q<j;q++)
    {
        s += '<'+ar[q];
    }
    i = s.search('</x:xmpmeta>');
    i += ('</x:xmpmeta>').length;
    s = s.slice(0,i);
    //Delete all behind the XMP XML
    //trace(s);
    return XML(s);
}
```

Comment: pretty sure XMP is never encrypted. It is just xml in the header of the file. You can verify this by opening up the file with notepad.

Comment: yes, that's why I am thinking its encrypted because in the wordpad the XMP headers aren't showing at all. It's all showing as byte data but yet in Photoshop the EXIF and XMP data exists and display, could the data then be serialized instead? and perhaps that is why its not showing?

Comment: I would search for the <?xpacket begin and <?xpacket end then you will know all data in that node is xmp-xml

Comment: also I think you are confusing yourself a little. why would cannon use an adobe NS xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/"

Comment: When I view the data in Photoshop I see this: <?xpacket begin="" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.3-c011 66.145661, 2012/02/06-14:56:27        ">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:aux="http://ns.adobe.com/exif/1.0/aux/">
         <aux:SerialNumber>3334444333344</aux:SerialNumber>
         <aux:LensInfo>18/1 55/1 0/0 0/0</aux:LensInfo> sorry about messy code, in wordpad no <? start its all as byte data. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's been about 4-5 years since I had to parse and write xmp/EXIF data but I vaguely remember cannon not being a team player. Something about RAW files I remember the xmp data is stored in a separate file. Oh and never use "WordPad" to look at code Microsoft products do not play nice with special characters use notepad.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, :) ok will look into it, so how did you get around this, did you read the seperate file?

Comment: ok been reading up a bit on it, and its suppose to be in the sidecar file right? But im a little confused, is the sidecar file PART of the image or an actual seperate file?  If I use the following code I see some XMP data but only a part of it:

var fileXmp:as3_xmp_file = new as3_xmp_file(picLoad);
      
      trace("checkIfFileFormatIsValid: " + fileXmp.xmpFile.checkIfFileFormatIsValid());
      trace("fileXmp.hasXmp : " + fileXmp.xmpFile.xmp.serializeToXML(null));
      trace("hasXmp : " + fileXmp.xmpFile.xmp);

So on my trace I actually see some XMP data, so its a start:

Comment: <x:xmpmeta x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.0.0-ac003" xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/">
  <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
    <rdf:Description rdf:about=""/>
  </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>